# Foreign Keys in yii2.0

Tags: yii2

Is there any possibility to create code using MODEL and CRUD-generator, which is able to read out foreign keys like this

"
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
"

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a forum. Please try to describe your technical problem  so that someone can provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yii's model generator will automatically create relations, if your constraints are set up correctly in your DB.